# Compiler warned me for making a fragment package-private; any other options?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, access-modifiers

Any other options to "hide" a fragment from components outside of the package it resides in?

I've tried using it package-private (default) modifier but the compiler gave me a warning:

[image]

Which is rather weird as package-private activities are just fine by them.